# Why the buttons are not removing active state when clicking another button?

Tags: javascript, css, button

I wanted that, when you click a button it receives a class called "active", and the others buttons if they have that active class, it should been removed. But when I click the B button, the active class of the A button is removed, but when I click the A button the active class still exists in the B button.

```js
const buttonList = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");

        buttonList.forEach((element) => {
            element.addEventListener("click", function () {
                document.querySelector(".rating").classList.remove("active");
                element.classList.add("active");
            });
        });
```

```css
.active {   background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<button class="rating">A</button>
      <button class="rating">B</button>
```

Comment: Because you are only selecting the first element that matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector(".rating")` only  matches the first element. So you are always selecting the first rating element and removing a class it may or may not have.

If only one element can be selected, select the one with the class.

```js
const prevSelected = document.querySelector(".rating.selected");
if (prevSelected) {
  prevSelected.classList.remove("active");
}
```

It can also be written as

```js
document.querySelector(".rating.selected")?.classList.remove("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all buttons, remove "active" class from them, and then make active current button.
Created a demo to solve this:

```js
const buttonList = document.querySelectorAll(".rating");

buttonList.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".rating")
    buttons.forEach((b) => {
      b.classList.remove("active");
    })


    element.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<button class="rating">A</button>

<button class="rating">B</button>
```